# How to prevent loading .git file while syncing a single file to aws s3

Tags: amazon-s3

UseD include/exclude options for the sync-directory command:

e.g. To sync just /var/local/path/filename.xyz to S3 useD:

s3 sync /var/local/path s3://bucket/path --exclude='*' --include='*/filename.xyz'
I could successfully sync my file but my .git file are also got uploaded which I did not want. How to keep .git file from loading while syncing a single file.